# Active Directory authentication via spring security returns bad credential for valid users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory

I have a spring based application on which I'm trying to implement spring security and authenticate against my Active Directory. I saw a good example on

[Active Directory Authentication using Spring Security 3.2, Spring Ldap 2.0 and JavaConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295616/active-directory-authentication-using-spring-security-3-2-spring-ldap-2-0-and-j)

but I dont have role based authorities in my application. Is there a way to avoid that userAuthoritiesMapper while authenticating via spring security?.

here is the config i have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder)
        throws Exception {

    authManagerBuilder
            .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());

}
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
            "mydomain.com",
            "ldaps://URL:636");
    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
            .setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
            .setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/Pages/Login.jsp")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
    // .and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
}
```

Comment: set the `authoritiesMapper` property and use the [`NullAuthoritiesMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/authority/mapping/NullAuthoritiesMapper.html) if you don't need roles.

Comment: thank you @M.Deinum for your response. I tried setting the authoritiesMapper to take NullAuthoritiesMapper but still cant get pass the bad credential for valid users. Would you happen to know why? and so far as i know the domain and url is correct.

Comment: Bad credentials is bad credentials. You could enable debug logging (or trace) logging to get more insight what is happening.

Comment: @M.Deinum how would i do that? I could save a lot of time if you have an example.